# Compare order of two HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function which accepts two parameters, each of type HTML element. It is supposed to return which element appears first in the document order. Is there any simple way to determine this?

Template -

```
 <body>
     <div id="div1">
          <div id="div2">
          </div>
     </div>
     <div id="div3">
        <div id="div4">
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

JS -

```
const elem1 = document.getElementById('div2');
const elem2 = document.getElementById('div4');
const firstAppearingElement = checkOrder(elem1, elem2); // it should return elem1
function checkOrder(element1, element2) {
    // check which one appears first in dom tree
}
```

Comment: You are strongly encouraged to include in your question approaches you have already tried.

Comment: Your question / concept is unclear.
Please provide us with a more detailed description as to what you are trying to accomplish so we can help you more efficiently.

Comment: @amn what document? the HTML document? a JSON file?

Comment: I removed my comment because `checkOrder` is a bit vague. Nevertheless, most other detail -- including what I had mentioned in the comment -- are there. Also, it says in the question: "HTML element", referring to your comment above. Where do you infer anything about "JSON file[s]"?

Comment: I have downvoted the question because it does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try with  [Node.compareDocumentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition)

> The Node.compareDocumentPosition() method compares the position of the
>   given node against another node in any document.

The syntax is `object.compareDocumentPosition (nodeToCompare);`

```js
let first = document.getElementById('a');
let second=document.getElementById('b');

// Because the result returned by compareDocumentPosition() is a bitmask, the bitwise AND operator has to be used for meaningful results.See link above for more

if (first.compareDocumentPosition(second) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING) {
  console.log('element with id a is before element with id b'); // 
} else {
  console.log('element with id a is after element with id b');
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>

<div id="b"></div>
```

Comment: When you first provide an idiomatic solution, fitting perfectly to asked question, I'd at least make the best of it by, for instance, removing ambiguity with `'before'` and `'after'` -- what is before what and what is after what? Likewise, your HTML snippet is absolutely unnecessary -- it's implied this is DOM and the snippet deals with DOM nodes. Other than that, like I said, a very fitting answer!